# Как реализовать скачивание CSV-файла клиенту с сервера?

Tags: python, python-3.x, webapp2

Использую `WebApp2`. Клиент зашел на Web-страницу - там сформировался в памяти `csv-файл`. Теперь я хочу, чтобы клиент его получил (скачал себе) автоматом.

**Дополнение:**

Реализовал скачивание файла:

```
def get(self):
    allRows = dbUser.query()
    DataForCSV_File = [['name', 'email']]
    for rows in allRows:
            DataForCSV_File.append([rows.name, rows.email])
    file_name = 'dbUser.csv'
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{0}"'.format(file_name)
    self.response.headers['File-Name'] = file_name
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
    self.response.write(DataForCSV_File)
```

В итоге после скачивания - открывается таблица `Excel` и в 1ой ячейке текстом записан список.

Пробовал `DataForCSV` преобразовывать:

```
f = StringIO()
csv.writer(f).writerows(DataForCSV_File)
```

В итоге при открытии в 1ой ячейке лежит:

```
<StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x3e10a6ff44d0>
```

Вопрос что я не так  делаю? Почему у меня не открывается нормальная CSV-таблица?

Comment: `Пробовал DataForCSV преобразовывать ... В итоге при открытии в 1ой ячейке лежит <StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x3e10a6ff44d0>` - мысль верная, просто после записи всех данных в StringIO нужно их оттуда как текст извлечь через `f.getvalue()`, а не возвращать объект StringIO как есть.

Comment: @insolor, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря @insolor, был найден конечный пазл! Может кто столкнется с такой проблемой вот полное решение в WebApp2:

```
def get(self):
    # Выборка всех пользователей из таблицы "dbUser"
    allRows = dbUser.query()
    
    # Подготовка данных для CSV-таблицы. 1 список в списке - название колонок
    DataForCSV_File = [['name', 'email']]
    
    # заполнение данных из выборки
    for rows in allRows:
        DataForCSV_File.append([rows.name, rows.email, rows.account_type])
    
    # Сохраняем данные будущего CSV-файла в памяти
    f = StringIO()
    csv.writer(f).writerows(DataForCSV_File)

    file_name = 'dbUser.csv'
    
    # Даем понимание браузеру, что ответ - это CSV-файл
    self.response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{0}"'.format(file_name)
    self.response.headers['File-Name'] = file_name
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/csv'
    
    # Извлекаем данные из памяти и отправляем пользователю.
    self.response.write(f.getvalue())
```

В итоге если этот метод указать для класса, то скачается CSV-файл!

Comment: Если будет проблема с кодировкой: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374576/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c/1374597#:~:text=encodeName_cp1251%20%3D%20name.encode(%22cp1251%22%2C%20%22ignore%22)

Answer (score 0):

если вы используете django, то можно использовать StreamingHttpResponse для реализации.

Comment: использую WebApp2