# Как узнать в какой кодировке данные или как правильно декодировать?

Tags: python, кодировка, python-2.x

Есть значение, но неизвестно в какой кодировке. Требуется перекодировать в UTF-8. Можно ли как-нибудь узнать в какой кодировке или автоматически их правильно декодировать?

Пробовал так:

```
decodeName = name.encode(encoding='UTF-8', errors='replace')
```

Но, в ответе получаются кракозябры *(например: **Р”Р°СЂСЊСЏ**)*, т.к. символы, которые не получилось закодировать - [пропускались](https://pythonstart.ru/string/encode-python).

Пробовал сделать так:

```
decodeNameASCII = name.decode("ascii")
encodeNameUTF8 = decodeNameASCII.encode("utf-8", "ignore")
```

Но выдает ошибку:

```
decodeNameASCI = name.decode("ascii")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Пробовал так:

```
decodeNameCP1251 = name.decode("cp1251")
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
decodeNameCP1251 = name.decode("cp1251")
File ".....python2.7/encodings/cp1251.py", line 15, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Чисто теоретически можно попробовать угадать кодировку - путем подстановки, но, думаю, это жестко.

**Python v2**

Дополнение:

1. Выборка из БД:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
....
from google.appengine.datastore.datastore_query import Cursor
cursor = self.request.get('cursor')
if cursor != 'undefined':
    cursor = Cursor(urlsafe=cursor)
    allRows, cursor, more = User.query().fetch_page(1000, start_cursor=cursor)
else:
    allRows, cursor, more = User.query().fetch_page(1000)

for rows in allRows:
    name = rows.name
    decodeName = name.encode(encoding='UTF-8', errors='replace')
    ....
```

2. Поле `name` в таблице БД может быть пустым, полностью из английских букв, полностью из русских и в перемешку (рус+англ+цифры)
3. Запись в файл:

```
DataForCSV_File.append([decodeName, rows.email, rows.account_type])
f = StringIO()
csv.writer(f).writerows(DataForCSV_File)
file_name = 'dbUser.csv'
```

4. Более подробно формирование файла и выборка была [в другом моем вопросе:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1373339/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-csv-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133470/discussion-on-question-by---------).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня получилось декодировать вашу строку следующими способами:

**Python 3**

```
'Р”Р°СЂСЊСЏ'.encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')
```

**Python 2**

```
bytes('Р”Р°СЂСЊСЏ').decode('utf-8').encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')
```

Ответ

```
Дарья
```

Comment: Ошибка: **nameDecode = bytes(name).decode('utf-8').encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)**

Comment: @АлексейБелкин вы пытаетесь закодировать и потом обратно декодировать юникодную строку. Не надо ничего делать, ваша строка `Дарья` уже и так успешно декодировалась автоматически

Comment: Похоже на то. Строка, что была предоставлена, скорее всего скопирована с терминала, который сам сделал дополнительную перекодировку, чтобы отобразить необходимые символы.

Comment: @GrAnd, строка скопирована из ячейки csv-файла

Comment: @АлексейБелкин Так может вам вашу строку (которая, судя по всему, из БД получена в кодировке utf-8) перед или во время записи в csv-файл перевести в кодировку cp1251 (которую наверняка и ожидает там увидеть Excel)?

Comment: @GrAnd, Спасибо! Действительно, сделал как и посоветовали, все заработало - стало нормально отображать без кракозябр: **encodeName_cp1251 = name.encode("cp1251", "ignore")**

Comment: @АлексейБелкин Кстати, если csv-файл записать в кодировке utf-8, но с [заголовком (BOM)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2#:~:text=8%5Bt%201%5D-,EF%20BB%20BF,-239%20187%20191), то Excel такой файл тоже распознаёт корректно.

Comment: @GrAnd, не подскажите как это сделать в памяти через **StringIO()**, просто сейчас смотрел у него нет атрибута **encode()**

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133472/discussion-between---and-grand).