# Проблема с кодировкой при записи в csv python

Tags: python-3.x, парсер, csv

Понимаю что вопрос нубский,  а код овно.
Но не могу разобраться с кодировкой при записи в csv. Python 3.7
Пишу из под винды 10 и pycharm

Ниже код и приме того как записывается .
Помогите разобраться. Спасибо

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import csv

url = 'https://www.avito.ru/krasnodar/kvartiry/prodam/vtorichka-ASgBAgICAkSSA8YQ5geMUg'
headers = {'accept': '*/*',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36'
           }

flats = {
    'title': None,
    'price': None,
    'address': None,
    'href': None
}

# Создаем CSV файл с заголовками для дальнейшей записи в него полученных параметров
with open('flats.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(['Заголовок', 'Цена', 'Адрес', 'Ссылка'])
#
req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
src = req.text
with open('index_1.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(src)
print('Обработка и скачивание страницы 1 завершено')
for i in range(2, 11):
    req = requests.get(f'{url}' + '?p=' + str(i))
    src = req.text
    with open(f'index_{i}.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(src)
    print(f'Обработка и скачивание страницы {i} завершено')
print('Запускаю обратботку информации на скачаных страницах')

for i in range(1, 11):
    with open(f'index_{i}.html', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
        src = file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
    cards_offers = soup.find('div', {'data-marker': 'catalog-serp'})
    cards = cards_offers.find_all('div', class_="iva-item-content-rejJg")

    for element in cards:
        # Достаем заголовок
        title_res = element.find('div', class_="iva-item-titleStep-pdebR").text
        title = str(title_res).replace(' ', '')
        # Достаем ссылку на объявление
        href_res = element.find('a').get('href')
        href = str('https://www.avito.ru' + href_res)
        # Достаем цену за квартиру
        price = str(element.find('span', class_="price-text-_YGDY text-text-LurtD text-size-s-BxGpL").text.replace('₽',
                                                                                                               '').replace(
            ' ', ''))
        address = str(element.find('span', class_="geo-address-fhHd0 text-text-LurtD text-size-s-BxGpL").text)

        flats.update({'title': title,
                      'price': price,
                      'address': address,
                      'href': href
                      })

        with open('flats.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow([flats['title'], flats['price'], flats['address'], flats['href']])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня была такая же проблема. Я задавался уже этим вопросом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1374576/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c

Comment: не помогло к сожалению

Comment: вопрос не только в кодировке в которой вы пишите, но и в том в какой кодировке ожидает получить данные программа, которая показывает csv файл на экране. У вас программа просмотра csv явно позволяет указать кодировку при открытии файла ?

Comment: Настройка Excel помогла.  
Но не понятна причина. Хотелось бы получать готовый файл
После обработки файлов, получается что основные данные читаемы, а заголовки кракозябры

Comment: В ссылке которой я указал, там писали, что Excel ожидает кодировку **cp-1251** : https://clck.ru/dYmA6

Comment: with open('flats.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
            writer.writerow([flats['title'], flats['price'], flats['address'], flats['href']])
Вот тут не хочет записывать в файл без encoding='utf-8'


А тут пишет без проблем
with open('flats.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow(['Заголовок', 'Цена', 'Адрес', 'Ссылка'])

Comment: @АлексейБелкин, Он может ее когда-то и ожидал, но сейчас прекрасно работает с `utf-8 with bom` что в python соответствует `utf-8-sig`

Answer (score 1):

> Собственно можно было в коментариях просто написать:
>
> ```py
> with open('flats.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file
> ```
>
> Но решил немного подшаманить ваш код

`pip install bs4 tqdm fake-useragent requests --upgrade`

### Вариант для python3.7

```py
import csv
import re
from unicodedata import normalize

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from bs4.element import Tag
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from requests import Session
from pathlib import Path

from tqdm import tqdm

ua = UserAgent()

s = Session()
s.headers.update(
    {
        'User-Agent': ua.firefox
    }
)
pages_for_fetch = 5

sheet_header = ['Заголовок', 'Цена', 'Адрес', 'Ссылка']


def pages_qty(pages_tag: Tag):
    return max(
        [
            int(item.get_text(strip=True))
            for item in pages_tag.find_all(
                'span',
                {'data-marker': re.compile(r'\(\d+\)$')}
            )
        ] or [1]
    )


base_url = 'https://www.avito.ru'
url = base_url + '/krasnodar/kvartiry/prodam/vtorichka-ASgBAgICAkSSA8YQ5geMUg?p=%s'


def snippet(ad_tag: Tag):
    price = None
    href = None
    address = None
    title = None

    tag = ad_tag.find('span', class_=re.compile(r'^geo-address-.+'))

    if tag:
        address = tag.get_text(strip=True)

    price_tg = ad_tag.find('span', class_=re.compile(r'^price-text-.*'))

    if price_tg:
        span = price_tg.find('span')
        if span:
            span.replace_with('')

        price = normalize('NFKC', price_tg.get_text(strip=True)).replace(' ', '')

    tag = ad_tag.find('h3', class_=re.compile(r'^title-root-.*'))
    if tag:
        title = tag.get_text(strip=True)

        a = tag.find_parent('a')
        if a:
            href = base_url + a.get('href')

    return dict(
        zip(
            sheet_header,
            (
                normalize('NFKC', title),
                price,
                normalize('NFKC', address),
                href
            )
        )
    )


def page(page_number: int):
    response = s.get(
        url % page_number
    )
    soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # print(f'Обработка и скачивание страницы {page_number} завершено')

    # Если прям очень хочется сохранять страницы, то можно так
    Path(__file__).parent.joinpath(f'page_{page_number}.html').write_text(soup.prettify(), encoding='utf-8')

    return map(snippet, soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile(r'^iva-item-body-.+'))), pages_qty(soup)


pg, qty = page(1)

total_pages = min(pages_for_fetch, qty)

ads = [*pg] + [
    elem for item, _ in [
        page(num) for num in tqdm(range(2, total_pages + 1), initial=1, total=total_pages)
    ] for elem in item
]

with open('flats.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        file,
        sheet_header,
        delimiter=',',
        dialect='unix'
    )
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(ads)
```

### Для 3.8 и выше:

```py
import csv
import re
from unicodedata import normalize

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from bs4.element import Tag
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from requests import Session

ua = UserAgent()

s = Session()
s.headers.update(
    {
        'User-Agent': ua.firefox
    }
)
pages_for_fetch = 5

sheet_header = ['Заголовок', 'Цена', 'Адрес', 'Ссылка']


def pages_qty(pages_tag: Tag):
    return max(
        [
            int(item.get_text(strip=True))
            for item in pages_tag.find_all(
                'span',
                {'data-marker': re.compile(r'\(\d+\)$')}
            )
        ] or [1]
    )


base_url = 'https://www.avito.ru'
url = base_url + '/krasnodar/kvartiry/prodam/vtorichka-ASgBAgICAkSSA8YQ5geMUg?p=%s'


def snippet(ad_tag: Tag):
    price = None
    href = None

    address = tag.get_text(strip=True) if (
        tag := ad_tag.find('span', class_=re.compile(r'^geo-address-.+'))
    ) else None

    if price_tg := ad_tag.find('span', class_=re.compile(r'^price-text-.*')):
        if span := price_tg.find('span'):
            span.replace_with('')

        price = normalize('NFKC', price_tg.get_text(strip=True)).replace(' ', '')

    title = tag.get_text(strip=True) if (
        tag := ad_tag.find('h3', class_=re.compile(r'^title-root-.*'))
    ) else None

    if tag:
        href = base_url + a.get('href') if (
            a := tag.find_parent('a')
        ) else None

    return dict(
        zip(
            sheet_header,
            (
                normalize('NFKC', title),
                price,
                normalize('NFKC', address),
                href
            )
        )
    )


def page(page_number: int):
    response = s.get(
        url % page_number
    )

    soup = Soup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    return map(snippet, soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile(r'^iva-item-body-.+'))), pages_qty(soup)


pg, qty = page(1)

ads = [*pg] + [
    elem for item, _ in [
        page(num) for num in range(2, min(pages_for_fetch, qty) + 1)
    ] for elem in item
]

with open('flats.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(
        file,
        sheet_header,
        delimiter=',',
        dialect='unix'
    )
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(ads)
```

> P.S. `pages_for_fetch` предназначена для того, чтобы указать количество страниц для парсинга

> P.P.S И еще один совет. Не используйте `excel` для работы с `csv` да и вообще с любыми файлами созданными не в `excel`. Велика вероятность того, что `Excel` сломает эти данные. (За исключением тех случаев когда данные подтягиваются через `PowerQuery`). Используйте, к примеру, `Clac` из `LibreOffice`. Намного корректней работает.